# barcode blending vs. min cut stitching

Tags: image-processing

I am having a problem understanding what barcode blending is good for?
and when it could be better than min-cut stitching?

thanks.
benny.

Comment: Maybe you should define what you are talking about a bit better... this question is currently the top google hit for either of those terms.

Comment: well... I guess it's not such a known subject.
min-cut
http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1950-g/results/proj3/dkendall/
barcode blending is a little bit harder to explain :(
basically if you have n pictures I1,I2,...,In with little motions between Ij and I(j+1) so suppose n is even you take I1,I3,...,I(n-1) and make a panorama out of them and you take I2,I4,...,In and make a panorama out of them 2 and finally you take the two panoramas and blend them together. how? with a mask that looks like a barcode, you put white strip where the I1 goes, the black where I2 goes and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Barcode blending is good for stitching narrow strips. It also presents a substantial improvement in speed and memory for mosaic blending and is trivial to implement while giving a results that are better than traditional mosaic blending.

The main purpose of this algorithm is for generating 3D images from a single panning camera. You can see more details in here:
http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~peleg/papers/iwvp11-vivet.pdf